# Running training the discriminator with more examples

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

As I understand what of the diff between regular GAN to WGAN is that we train the discriminator/critic with more examples in each epoch. If in the regular gan we have in each epoch one batch for both modules, in WGAN we will have 5 batches (or more) for the discriminator and one for the generator.

So basically we have another inner loop for the discriminator :

```
real_images_labels = np.ones((BATCH_SIZE, 1))
 fake_images_labels = -real_images_labels
 for epoch in range(epochs):
    for batch in range(NUM_BACHES):
        for critic_iter in range(n_critic):
        random_batches_idx = np.random.randint(0, NUM_BACHES) # Choose random batch from dataset
        imgs_data=dataset_list[random_batches_idx]
        c_loss_real = critic.train_on_batch(imgs_data, real_images_labels) # update the weights after 1 batch

        noise = tf.random.normal([imgs_data.shape[0], noise_dim]) # Generate noise data
        generated_images = generator(noise, training=True)
        c_loss_fake = critic.train_on_batch(generated_images, fake_images_labels)  # update the weights after 1 batch
      
    
      imgs_data=dataset_list[batch]
      noise = tf.random.normal([imgs_data.shape[0], noise_dim]) # Generate noise data
      gen_loss_batch = gen_loss_batch + gan.train_on_batch(noise,real_images_labels)
```

The training is taking me a lot of time, per epoch about 3m. The idea I had to decrease the training time is instead running forward for each batch n_critic times I can increase the batch_size for the discriminator and run forward one time with a bigger batch_size.

I am seeking feedback: does it sound reasonable?

(I didn't paste my entire code, it was just a part of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does sound reasonable typically **increasing batch_size** during training, typically decreases the training time with a cost of using **more memory** and **lower accuracy** *(lower generalization ability)*.

Having said this you should do always do trial and error with regards to batching as extreme values may or may not increase the training time.

For further discussion you can refer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network)

Comment: first of all thank you for the answer. If I increase the batch size I'll have less weights updates. With iterations I update the weights more times , and each time per smaller batch. What will be the trade offs ?

Comment: Yes, exactly because you have increased the batch size the weights will be updated less thus resulting into lower accuracy. More Iterations with small batches will result into more accurate model compared to large batches but will be trained for a longer time. The trade off will be accuracy vs time, assuming there are no memory constraints.